# Videos on how to use Team Foundation Server for your Source Control

Tags: .net, tfs, version-control

Any good videos online on how to use Team Foundation Server as your Source Control repository? I need something quick to get me jump started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look at these?

http://teamsystemrocks.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple at [DimeCasts.Net](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/TFS)